# Receiving error unable to find entry point named glBindFramebuffer when creating a new GraphicsDeviceManager object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, monogame

I have a `Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'` when running a MonoGame Windows OpenGL project, So it seems the only way to solve this problem is to wrap a try and catch around it and then it will let you compile and run the program so my question is since I know that the new GraphicsDeviceManager fails will that result in a problem later on when deploying my game?.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the exact same error when I was trying to run my game in a virtual machine. It's essentially because you don't have the correct version of OpenGL installed. OpenGL normally comes with your graphics card drivers.

There is a discussion about this issue here:
https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/998

In terms of deployment you basically have 3 options:

- Use DirectX instead (plain old Microsoft XNA) or you can try MonoGame's DirectX implementation, but I'm not sure if it's complete.
- If you are targeting other platforms (Android, iOS, etc) you'll be using OpenGL on the devices, but this should be okay.
- Ensure your game has minimum requirements specified somewhere and handle the errors gracefully when it fails telling your users to update their graphics drivers.

That said, testing in different machine configurations is still a good idea.

Comment: Alright im guessing this is an issue on my part since my drivers arent good enough, so it should fail on MY computer..as long as the other users that play my game have openGL 4.0 they should be good right? like you said I can specify the requirements. thank you